# Can I show all the template files that are being used on my site?

Tags: theme-development, page-template

I have a legacy theme that has a lot of page template files. My site is too big to go through each page one by one to check it's template.

Is there any way (either through adding a column to the pages list in the the backend, or in the database directly) to see which templates files are being used and determine which are surplus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would add a column with the page template file name into the 'Pages' in the dashboard:

```
// ONLY WORDPRESS DEFAULT PAGES
add_filter('manage_page_posts_columns', 'custom_admin_columns_head', 10);
add_action('manage_page_posts_custom_column', 'custom_admin_columns_content', 10, 2);

// ADD NEW COLUMN
function custom_admin_columns_head($defaults) {
    $defaults['page_template_file'] = 'Page Template File';
    return $defaults;
}

// SHOW THE PAGE TEMPLATE FILE NAME
function custom_admin_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'page_template_file') {
        $page_template_file = get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
            echo ($page_template_file ? $page_template_file : '-');
    }
}
```

based on:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen--wp-24934

Answer (score 1):

The page template is saved into a post meta field called `_wp_page_template`. If no template is selected, the dropdown is showing »Default Template« in that case, then the value of the field will be `default`. Otherwise the meta field contains the filename, e.g. `page-template.php`. Or, if you have the templates in a subdirectory, e.g. `template-directory/page-templateXYZ.php`. Ergo you can query for the field not being `default`, giving you all pages using templates. Then we get the meta field values for those pages. In the end we make sure to get unique results, so every used template is only shown once.

```
$pages_with_templates = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'fields' => 'ids',
        'meta_query' => [[
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'default',
            'compare' => '!='
        ],],
] );
$pages_with_templates_ids = $pages_with_templates->posts;
$all_templates = [];
foreach ( $pages_with_templates_ids as $id ) {
    $all_templates[] = get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', true );
}
$unique_templates = array_unique( $all_templates );
```